# Как написать циклический скрипт VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Задача: Менять время в сводной таблице в соответствие с последним обновлением таблицы. 
Пример: Последнее обновление было в 15:00, в ячейку `J2` выводится 15(функция `ЧАС()`). Должно получится что то вроде этой записи макроса:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today").PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[Period].&[Night]")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today").PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[9]", "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[10]", _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[11]", "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[12]" _
    , "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[13]", _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[14]", "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[15]" _
    )
```

Мой код не работает, хотя ошибок не выдает

```
Dim N As Integer
Dim M As Integer
N = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today(MainSources)").Cells(2, 10).Value
M = 8
Do Until M > N

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today").PivotFields( _
        "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[Period].&[Night]")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today").PivotFields( _
        "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
        "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[M]")
        M = M + 1
        Loop
```

Comment: что такое `M = 8`? Если `N = 15`, то условие `M > N` не будет выполняться, соответственно код отрабатывает, но ничего кроме присваивания не делает

Comment: правильно понимаю, что нужны все временные периоды с 8:00 до 15:00?

Comment: @slippyk 1.отсчет должен начаться с 8 (так как от 1-8 выбирается с [Night] ). А разве Do Until M > N не означает что циклы должен продолжаться до момента когда M станет больше N, в данном случае 16? 2. Да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл правильный, но `M` подставляться в `"[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[M]"` не будет.

Я бы делал примерно так (проверить не на чем):

```
Dim WS_Main As Worksheet
Dim WS_Today As Worksheet
Dim StartUpdate As Long
Dim LastUpdate As Long
Dim Params() As String

Set WS_Main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today(MainSources)")
Set WS_Today = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stat Today")

StartUpdate = 8
LastUpdate = WS_Main.Cells(2, 10).Value
ReDim Params(LastUpdate - StartUpdate)

For M = StartUpdate To LastUpdate
    Params(M - StartUpdate) = "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[" & Trim(Str(M)) & "]"
Next M

WS_Today.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[Period]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[Period].&[Night]")

WS_Today.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13").PivotFields( _
    "[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H]").VisibleItemsList = Params
```

Comment: Пишет Run-time error '1004'
Не удается найти элемент в клубе OLAP(с добавленным `.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13")`). Заметил ошибку в своем коде перед `.PivotFields` не хватает `.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица13")`

Comment: а какую строчку при ошибке подсвечивает?

Comment: `WS_Today.PivotFields("[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H]").VisibleItemsList = Params`

Comment: попробуйте изменить `Str(M)` на `Trim(Str(M))`,первый вариант лишний пробел вставляет и получается `[Time HH].[Time by Periods].[H].&[ 15]`